# (Java) How to avoid null pointer exception when getting nested class element?

Tags: java, class, null, nested

I have a class like this one:

```
class Tickets{
    Data data;
    class Data{
        String departure;
    }
    public String getDeparture(){
        return data.departure;
    }

}
```

When I try something like this:

```
Tickets tickets=new Tickets();
if (tickets.getDeparture!=null)
```

I get nullpointerexception on this check. Why is that so? How can I avoid it? What to do instead?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Your code is invalid. And of course you get a NPE, `tickets` was never initialized.

Comment: You'd also get a NPE if `data` is null - avoid that with a check, e.g. `return data != null ? data.departure : null;`.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use object instance you have to create (initialize) it.

```
class Tickets{
    Data data = new Data(); // initialize data instance
    class Data{
        String departure;
    }
    public String getDeparture(){
        return data.departure
    }
}

Tickets tickets = new Tickets();
if (tickets.getDeparture!=null)
```

Just because you are using nested class in above case does not mean that you don't have to initialize `data` instance.

Since you are using above class for parsing JSON data, you can end up with `data` instance being `null` in case of invalid or missing JSON data even though it has been originally initialized with `tickets` instance.

To avoid that NPE you would have to add additional check if `data` is `null` in `getDeparture` method.

```
    public String getDeparture()
    {
        return data != null ? data.departure : null;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that. That was accidental error while posting code here . I intended to initialize it. But I still get nullpointerexception.

Comment: You need to initialize data instance also. See `Data data = new Data();`

Comment: i think the code is still wrong initialize departure variable too;

Comment: Is there any way it could be done automatically? For example could I initialize data instance in Tickets constructor?

Comment: @ Priyamal I am using null check for that reason. If I knew  it had been initialized to some value, there would no be need for null check.

Comment: Have you tried code I posted? It initializes data instance automatically when you create ticket instance. you can also use constructor if you wish, but it is not necessary in above example

Comment: The only thing that you need to additionally initialize is departure string instance, but your code that checks it for null is there for that purpose I presume.

Comment: Didn't see that line, sorry. That would probably work. I am using this nested class to parse JSON into these variables. Not sure if that would be problem if I initialize data instance that way.

Comment: OK, parsing is bit different. It depends on the parser, but you can easily end up with `data` being `null` even when you initialize it before parsing. If that is the case (when you have invalid or missing data) you will also have to add `null` check for `data` in `getDeparture` method.

Comment: Thanks, I think that your last code snippet is answer. I 'll check it.